# Cannot find NPM on AppData\Roaming

Tags: node.js

I'm starting learning nodejs with express, when I try to run the command "npx create-react-app my-app" I get several errors that npm was not found

*`npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.`*

The logs says:

*`verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\irami\AppData\Roaming\npm'`*

However, if I run the following

`npm config get prefix`

I get

`C:\Users{myname}\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Not quite understanding what is I'm doing wrong, or how to fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering an issue where **npx** is unable to find **npm**. This could be due to a misconfiguration or installation issue. To resolve this problem, you can try the following steps:

Verify Node.js and npm Installation: Ensure that Node.js and npm are installed correctly on your system. You can check their versions using the following commands:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If these commands return the version numbers, it means Node.js and npm are installed.

Check Environment Variables:

Make sure that the directory containing npm is included in your system's PATH environment variable.
Confirm that there are no typos or issues with your PATH configuration.
Update npm:

Run the following command to update npm to the latest version:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Clear npm Cache:

Sometimes, issues can arise due to a corrupted npm cache. You can clear the npm cache by running:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Check for Node.js Installation Path:

Ensure that the directory containing Node.js and npm is correctly set in your PATH.
If you installed Node.js and npm using a package manager like Chocolatey or Scoop, make sure the installation path is added to your PATH.
Reinstall Node.js and npm:

If the issue persists, consider reinstalling Node.js and npm from the official website. This can often resolve any configuration-related problems.
Restart Your Command Prompt or Terminal:

After making changes to your PATH or environment variables, it's essential to restart your command prompt or terminal to apply the changes.
Check for Multiple Versions:

Ensure that you don't have multiple versions of Node.js or npm installed on your system, which could lead to conflicts.
Check for Antivirus or Security Software:

Some antivirus or security software can interfere with npm and its functionality. Temporarily disabling such software may help diagnose the issue.
After trying these steps, attempt to run your npx create-react-app my-app command again. If the problem persists, please provide any error messages or additional details for further assistance.

Comment: "Try clearing the cache" — How?

Comment: "kill the server" — What server? `create-react-app` will *install* a development server which the OP could run … if the installed wasn't erroring out.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, that totally helped me fixing my issue.

Comment: Running `npm install -g npm` was the only thing that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: after updating npm (npm install -g npm), its worked for me

Comment: Clearing cache worked

Answer (score 1):

This actually worked for me:

1. Updated npm to the latest version

```bash
npm install -g npm@latest
```

2. Clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean -f
```

3. Delete node modules and package-lock.json

```bash
npm rm -rf node_modules

rm package-lock.json
```

4. Retry installing dependencies

```bash
npm install
```

After all those steps, I was able to see npm under `AppData\Roaming`.
Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Create an empty `npm` directory in `AppData` directory.

Then re-run `npx create-react-app my-app`.